# C# - Alto consumo de memória

Tags: c#, memória

Estou com problemas de consumo de memória de uma aplicação que recebe alertas de noticias em tempo real.
Sempre que uma noticia chega, ao abrir esta noticia, o consumo de memória cresce, mas não diminui na mesma proporção quando o formulario e fechado.
Tentei chamar o GC explicitamente ao fechar o formulario mas parece que não resolveu.

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Comparando o consumo registrado pelo diagnostic tools, consigo visualizar que o consumo esta sempre crescente e nunca retorna próximo do nível original de quando a aplicação foi inicializada.

Não sei quais pontos do código devo verificar para tentar diminuir o consumo de memória.

Comment: Chamar o GC não faz ele liberar memória diretamente, faz ele VERIFICAR se existem objetos não mais utilizados e enfim libera memória usada por eles. Se chamar o GC não funciona, ele deve estar entendendo que os objetos estão sendo usados.

Answer (score 0):

O `GC` (*Garbage Colector*) só liberta memória de *managed code* e/ou *managed resources*, onde em casos que não se englobam nesse cenário é necessário implementar rotinas para libertar "manualmente" a memória.

Os objetos que está a utilizar no processo de recolha das notícias poderá estar a utilizar recursos que não conseguem ser libertados pelo `GC`, assim como ficheiros, conexões de rede, ligações a base de dados, etc.

A solução passa por implementar, por exemplo, o [disposable pattern](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose), onde permite que a a memória e o objeto sejam corretamente libertados.

Outra forma é fazer um `override` ao método destrutor (`~MeuMetodo()`) e limpar a memória aí.

Pode consultar mais informação sobre este tema na documentação da **Microsoft**:

[Cleaning Up Unmanaged Resources](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/unmanaged)

Ou um bom artigo sobre o tema na **CodinGame**:

[Garbage Collection and C#](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/6179/garbage-collection-and-c)

Comment: Tentei implementar a interface IDispoable e fazer a sobrecarga do metodo destrutor, mas pude observar que em nenhum momento ele passa pelo metodo Dispose ou pelo destrutor. Ao que parece, enquanto esses objetos estão em memória dentro do workspace que controla as janelas, ele não passara por esses metodos.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente você não está limpando os objetos relativos à **notícia** à medida que o formulário é fechado.

O Garbage Collector (GC) vai limpar objetos que não estão sendo referenciados e promover para outra geração objetos antigos que ainda estão sendo referenciados.

Para você identificar quais são esses objetos, rode um Memory Profiler. 
Recomendo ANTS: https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/index

Gratuito por 14 dias. Em algumas iterações você conseguirá identificar qual é o objeto em questão.

Comment: Existe alguma ferramenta opensource que mostre pra mim quais são os objetos que consomem mais memoria?

Comment: Existe uma ferramenta da própria Microsoft que pode ajudar: o CLR Memory Profiler: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16273, ele vai dar um indicativo de como a memoria cresce e a utilização do GC  mas não mostra exatamente qual o objeto.

Com o VS 2015 Update 1 ou mais recente você pode tentar o memory profiler embutido com o VS: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2015.